# Longtable won't fit page width

Tags: longtable, width

I have this table that I want to fit over multiple pages, therefore `longtable`. Now it won't fit to the page width.

The table is pretty big...
The second and third column are coordinates and can't be shortened unfortunately...

````
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Design} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Kontrol} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Differens} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Gns.snit} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Sigma} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{d\_max} \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
%
\endhead
%
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Pkt.} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Easting} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Northing} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Easting} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Northing} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Easting} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Northing} &
  {\color[HTML]{202122} μ {[}m{]}} &
  {\color[HTML]{202122} σ {[}m{]}} &
  {[}m{]} \\ \hline
1  & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729598,741} & 6171261,02  & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729598,743} & 6171261,029 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-0,002} & -0,009 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
2  & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729598,897} & 6171260,664 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729598,909} & 6171260,669 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-0,012} & -0,005 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
3  & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729598,973} & 6171260,489 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729598,987} & 6171260,491 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-0,014} & -0,002 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
4  & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729591,938} & 6171258,298 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729591,935} & 6171258,284 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0,003}  & 0,014  &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
5  & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729592,087} & 6171257,93  & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729592,087} & 6171257,926 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0,000}  & 0,004  &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
6  & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729592,181} & 6171257,727 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729592,184} & 6171257,726 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-0,003} & 0,001  &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
7  & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729586,791} & 6171256,205 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729586,792} & 6171256,222 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-0,001} & -0,017 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
8  & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729586,931} & 6171255,84  & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729586,935} & 6171255,830 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-0,004} & 0,01   &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
9  & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729587,022} & 6171255,644 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729587,020} & 6171255,648 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0,002}  & -0,004 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
10 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729583,342} & 6171254,816 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729583,347} & 6171254,816 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-0,005} & 0,000  &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
11 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729583,489} & 6171254,435 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729583,499} & 6171254,431 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-0,010} & 0,004  &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
12 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729583,576} & 6171254,245 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729583,561} & 6171254,249 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0,015}  & -0,004 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
13 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729579,337} & 6171253,176 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729579,336} & 6171253,173 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0,001}  & 0,003  &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
14 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729579,438} & 6171252,864 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729579,449} & 6171252,857 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-0,011} & 0,007  &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
15 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729579,562} & 6171252,6   & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729579,553} & 6171252,603 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0,009}  & -0,003 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
16 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729575,731} & 6171251,687 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729575,729} & 6171251,683 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0,002}  & 0,004  &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
17 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729575,814} & 6171251,419 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729575,834} & 6171251,411 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-0,020} & 0,008  &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
18 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729575,958} & 6171251,135 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729575,952} & 6171251,134 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0,006}  & 0,001  &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
19 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729568,597} & 6171248,783 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729568,580} & 6171248,789 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0,017}  & -0,006 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
20 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729568,73}  & 6171248,412 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729568,726} & 6171248,417 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0,004}  & -0,005 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
21 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729568,795} & 6171248,231 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729568,803} & 6171248,223 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-0,008} & 0,008  &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
22 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729562,201} & 6171246,188 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729562,204} & 6171246,191 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-0,003} & -0,003 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
23 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729562,341} & 6171245,81  & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729562,334} & 6171245,818 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0,007}  & -0,008 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
24 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729562,41}  & 6171245,628 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729562,408} & 6171245,631 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0,002}  & -0,003 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
25 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729555,891} & 6171243,616 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729555,895} & 6171243,617 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-0,004} & -0,001 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
26 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729556,006} & 6171243,377 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729556,003} & 6171243,377 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0,003}  & 0,000  &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
27 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729556,112} & 6171243,069 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729556,105} & 6171243,079 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0,007}  & -0,010 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
28 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729550,186} & 6171241,296 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729550,182} & 6171241,300 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0,004}  & -0,004 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
29 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729550,305} & 6171241,07  & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729550,310} & 6171241,064 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-0,005} & 0,006  &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
30 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729550,411} & 6171240,743 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729550,415} & 6171240,747 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-0,004} & -0,004 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
31 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729538,652} & 6171236,606 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729538,662} & 6171236,611 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-0,010} & -0,005 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
32 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729538,803} & 6171236,231 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729538,816} & 6171236,234 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-0,013} & -0,003 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
33 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729538,879} & 6171236,044 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729538,889} & 6171236,045 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-0,010} & -0,001 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
34 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729533,279} & 6171234,425 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729533,290} & 6171234,444 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-0,011} & -0,019 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
35 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729533,426} & 6171234,044 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729533,440} & 6171234,043 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-0,014} & 0,001  &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
36 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729533,505} & 6171233,85  & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729533,499} & 6171233,856 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0,006}  & -0,006 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
37 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729528,457} & 6171232,45  & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729528,465} & 6171232,451 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-0,008} & -0,001 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
38 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729528,608} & 6171232,081 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729528,612} & 6171232,077 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-0,004} & 0,004  &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
39 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729528,686} & 6171231,903 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729528,680} & 6171231,902 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0,006}  & 0,001  &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
40 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729521,837} & 6171229,747 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729521,841} & 6171229,753 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-0,004} & -0,006 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
41 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729521,985} & 6171229,364 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729521,982} & 6171229,360 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0,003}  & 0,004  &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
42 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729522,063} & 6171229,185 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729522,063} & 6171229,184 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0,000}  & 0,001  &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
43 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729517,553} & 6171227,989 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729517,560} & 6171227,989 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-0,007} & 0,000  &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
44 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729517,709} & 6171227,629 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729517,708} & 6171227,634 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0,001}  & -0,005 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
45 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729517,78}  & 6171227,442 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729517,774} & 6171227,442 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0,006}  & 0,000  &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
46 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729513,038} & 6171226,164 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729513,042} & 6171226,161 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-0,004} & 0,003  &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
47 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729513,198} & 6171225,787 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729513,201} & 6171225,791 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-0,003} & -0,004 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
48 &
  \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729513,265} &
  6171225,606 &
  \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729513,284} &
  6171225,557 &
  \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-0,019} &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FF0000}0,049 &
   &
   &
   \\ \cline{1-7}
49 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729507,361} & 6171223,854 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729507,357} & 6171223,858 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0,004}  & -0,004 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
50 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729507,515} & 6171223,487 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729507,510} & 6171223,491 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0,005}  & -0,004 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
51 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729507,589} & 6171223,298 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729507,591} & 6171223,302 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-0,002} & -0,004 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
52 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729502,897} & 6171222,041 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729502,891} & 6171222,026 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0,006}  & 0,015  &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
53 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729503,061} & 6171221,668 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729503,062} & 6171221,659 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-0,001} & 0,009  &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
54 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729503,12}  & 6171221,49  & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729503,117} & 6171221,496 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0,003}  & -0,006 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
55 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729498,329} & 6171220,185 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729498,328} & 6171220,177 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0,001}  & 0,008  &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
56 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729498,478} & 6171219,801 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729498,488} & 6171219,807 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-0,010} & -0,006 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
57 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729498,557} & 6171219,624 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729498,552} & 6171219,632 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0,005}  & -0,008 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
58 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729584,389} & 6171255,864 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729584,388} & 6171255,868 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0,001}  & -0,004 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
59 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729517,339} & 6171228,518 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729517,338} & 6171228,516 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0,001}  & 0,002  &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
60 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729543,328} & 6171239,092 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729543,333} & 6171239,102 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-0,005} & -0,010 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
61 &
  \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729558,679} &
  6171245,372 &
  \multicolumn{1}{r|}{729558,693} &
  6171245,371 &
  \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-0,014} &
  0,001 &
  \multirow{-61}{*}{-0,001} &
  \multirow{-61}{*}{0,008} &
  \multirow{-61}{*}{0,025} \\ \hline
\caption{Beregning af afsætning - undergruppe 3a}
\label{tab:afs_beregn_3a}\\
\end{longtable}```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The material in columns 8 thru 10 appears to be identical for all rows. Hence, why not take it out of the table and decrease the column count from 10 to 7?

If that's not permissible, I suggest you typeset the `longtable` in landscape mode, as is done in the following code and associated screenshot.

I would also align the numbers on their decimal markers. And, to improve the table's overall readability, I suggest you get rid of all `\cline` directives and, instead, insert a bit of whitespace after every 5th row or so to create a better sense of visual grouping.

Last but not least, do please get rid of the pointless `\multicolumn{1}{r|}` wrappers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}  % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}

% new:
\usepackage{pdflscape} % for 'landscape' environment
\usepackage{siunitx} % for 'S' col. type
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}, group-digits=false}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{@{}
        S[table-format= 2.0] 
   *{2}{S[table-format= 6.3]S[table-format= 7.3]}
   *{3}{S[table-format=-1.3]}
   *{2}{S[table-format= 1.3]}
   @{}}

%% headers and footers 
\toprule
  {Pkt.} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Design} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kontrol} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Differens} &
  {Gns.snit $\mu$} & 
  {Sigma $\sigma$} & 
  {d\_max} \\ 
  \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
  & {Easting} & {Northing} 
  & {Easting} & {Northing} 
  & {Easting} & {Northing} &
  {\color[HTML]{202122} [m]} &
  {\color[HTML]{202122} [m]} &
  {[m]} \\ 
  \midrule
\endhead

\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\caption{Beregning af afsætning - undergruppe 3a}
\label{tab:afs_beregn_3a}
\endlastfoot

%% body of longtable
1  & 729598,741 & 6171261,02  & 729598,743 & 6171261,029 & -0,002 & -0,009 & -0,001 & 0,008 & 0,025 \\ 
2  & 729598,897 & 6171260,664 & 729598,909 & 6171260,669 & -0,012 & -0,005 \\ 
3  & 729598,973 & 6171260,489 & 729598,987 & 6171260,491 & -0,014 & -0,002 \\ 
4  & 729591,938 & 6171258,298 & 729591,935 & 6171258,284 & 0,003  & 0,014  \\ 
5  & 729592,087 & 6171257,93  & 729592,087 & 6171257,926 & 0,000  & 0,004  \\ \addlinespace
6  & 729592,181 & 6171257,727 & 729592,184 & 6171257,726 & -0,003 & 0,001  \\ 
7  & 729586,791 & 6171256,205 & 729586,792 & 6171256,222 & -0,001 & -0,017 \\ 
8  & 729586,931 & 6171255,84  & 729586,935 & 6171255,830 & -0,004 & 0,01   \\ 
9  & 729587,022 & 6171255,644 & 729587,020 & 6171255,648 & 0,002  & -0,004 \\ 
10 & 729583,342 & 6171254,816 & 729583,347 & 6171254,816 & -0,005 & 0,000  \\ \addlinespace
11 & 729583,489 & 6171254,435 & 729583,499 & 6171254,431 & -0,010 & 0,004  \\ 
12 & 729583,576 & 6171254,245 & 729583,561 & 6171254,249 & 0,015  & -0,004 \\ 
13 & 729579,337 & 6171253,176 & 729579,336 & 6171253,173 & 0,001  & 0,003  \\ 
14 & 729579,438 & 6171252,864 & 729579,449 & 6171252,857 & -0,011 & 0,007  \\ 
15 & 729579,562 & 6171252,6   & 729579,553 & 6171252,603 & 0,009  & -0,003 \\ \addlinespace
16 & 729575,731 & 6171251,687 & 729575,729 & 6171251,683 & 0,002  & 0,004  \\ 
17 & 729575,814 & 6171251,419 & 729575,834 & 6171251,411 & -0,020 & 0,008  \\ 
18 & 729575,958 & 6171251,135 & 729575,952 & 6171251,134 & 0,006  & 0,001  \\ 
19 & 729568,597 & 6171248,783 & 729568,580 & 6171248,789 & 0,017  & -0,006 \\ 
20 & 729568,73  & 6171248,412 & 729568,726 & 6171248,417 & 0,004  & -0,005 \\ \addlinespace
21 & 729568,795 & 6171248,231 & 729568,803 & 6171248,223 & -0,008 & 0,008  \\ 
22 & 729562,201 & 6171246,188 & 729562,204 & 6171246,191 & -0,003 & -0,003 \\ 
23 & 729562,341 & 6171245,81  & 729562,334 & 6171245,818 & 0,007  & -0,008 \\ 
24 & 729562,41  & 6171245,628 & 729562,408 & 6171245,631 & 0,002  & -0,003 \\ 
25 & 729555,891 & 6171243,616 & 729555,895 & 6171243,617 & -0,004 & -0,001 \\ \addlinespace
26 & 729556,006 & 6171243,377 & 729556,003 & 6171243,377 & 0,003  & 0,000  \\ 
27 & 729556,112 & 6171243,069 & 729556,105 & 6171243,079 & 0,007  & -0,010 \\ 
28 & 729550,186 & 6171241,296 & 729550,182 & 6171241,300 & 0,004  & -0,004 \\ 
29 & 729550,305 & 6171241,07  & 729550,310 & 6171241,064 & -0,005 & 0,006  \\ 
30 & 729550,411 & 6171240,743 & 729550,415 & 6171240,747 & -0,004 & -0,004 \\ \addlinespace
31 & 729538,652 & 6171236,606 & 729538,662 & 6171236,611 & -0,010 & -0,005 \\ 
32 & 729538,803 & 6171236,231 & 729538,816 & 6171236,234 & -0,013 & -0,003 \\ 
33 & 729538,879 & 6171236,044 & 729538,889 & 6171236,045 & -0,010 & -0,001 \\ 
34 & 729533,279 & 6171234,425 & 729533,290 & 6171234,444 & -0,011 & -0,019 \\ 
35 & 729533,426 & 6171234,044 & 729533,440 & 6171234,043 & -0,014 & 0,001  \\ \addlinespace
36 & 729533,505 & 6171233,85  & 729533,499 & 6171233,856 & 0,006  & -0,006 \\ 
37 & 729528,457 & 6171232,45  & 729528,465 & 6171232,451 & -0,008 & -0,001 \\ 
38 & 729528,608 & 6171232,081 & 729528,612 & 6171232,077 & -0,004 & 0,004  \\ 
39 & 729528,686 & 6171231,903 & 729528,680 & 6171231,902 & 0,006  & 0,001  \\ 
40 & 729521,837 & 6171229,747 & 729521,841 & 6171229,753 & -0,004 & -0,006 \\ \addlinespace
41 & 729521,985 & 6171229,364 & 729521,982 & 6171229,360 & 0,003  & 0,004  \\ 
42 & 729522,063 & 6171229,185 & 729522,063 & 6171229,184 & 0,000  & 0,001  \\ 
43 & 729517,553 & 6171227,989 & 729517,560 & 6171227,989 & -0,007 & 0,000  \\ 
44 & 729517,709 & 6171227,629 & 729517,708 & 6171227,634 & 0,001  & -0,005 \\ 
45 & 729517,78  & 6171227,442 & 729517,774 & 6171227,442 & 0,006  & 0,000  \\ \addlinespace
46 & 729513,038 & 6171226,164 & 729513,042 & 6171226,161 & -0,004 & 0,003  \\ 
47 & 729513,198 & 6171225,787 & 729513,201 & 6171225,791 & -0,003 & -0,004 \\ 
48 & 729513,265 & 6171225,606 & 729513,284 & 6171225,557 & -0,019 & \cellcolor[HTML]{FF0000} 0,049 \\ 
49 & 729507,361 & 6171223,854 & 729507,357 & 6171223,858 & 0,004  & -0,004 \\ 
50 & 729507,515 & 6171223,487 & 729507,510 & 6171223,491 & 0,005  & -0,004 \\ \addlinespace
51 & 729507,589 & 6171223,298 & 729507,591 & 6171223,302 & -0,002 & -0,004 \\ 
52 & 729502,897 & 6171222,041 & 729502,891 & 6171222,026 & 0,006  & 0,015  \\ 
53 & 729503,061 & 6171221,668 & 729503,062 & 6171221,659 & -0,001 & 0,009  \\ 
54 & 729503,12  & 6171221,49  & 729503,117 & 6171221,496 & 0,003  & -0,006 \\ 
55 & 729498,329 & 6171220,185 & 729498,328 & 6171220,177 & 0,001  & 0,008  \\ \addlinespace
56 & 729498,478 & 6171219,801 & 729498,488 & 6171219,807 & -0,010 & -0,006 \\ 
57 & 729498,557 & 6171219,624 & 729498,552 & 6171219,632 & 0,005  & -0,008 \\ 
58 & 729584,389 & 6171255,864 & 729584,388 & 6171255,868 & 0,001  & -0,004 \\ 
59 & 729517,339 & 6171228,518 & 729517,338 & 6171228,516 & 0,001  & 0,002  \\ 
60 & 729543,328 & 6171239,092 & 729543,333 & 6171239,102 & -0,005 & -0,010 \\ \addlinespace
61 & 729558,679 & 6171245,372 & 729558,693 & 6171245,371 & -0,014 &  0,001 \\

\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The third and fifth columns have 7 integer digits, not six. This is more visible if you enable grouping of digits. See edit in my answer.

Comment: @Zarko - Thanks for noticing this issue. I've updated the code and screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

A variation of nice @Mico answer (+1) with use of `tabularray`. package. Table width is equal to `\linewidth` (= `\textheight`):

**Edit (1):**
Now is corrected specification for the third and fifth columns. From 6 integer digits in orginal answer are corrected to 7 as numbers in these columns have.

**Edit (2):**
Added is code for use of colors based on HTML color model. Additionally is a wee bit changed table specification, which make row spacing more correct:

```
\documentclass{article}  % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
%\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape} % for 'landscape' environment

\usepackage{xcolor,
            %colortbl   % not needed
            }
% new:
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx} 

    \NewTblrTheme{fancy}{
    \SetTblrStyle{head}{font=\small}
    \SetTblrStyle{foot}{font=\footnotesize}
    \SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{font=\bfseries}
                        }
\makeatletter   % new, added
      \ExplSyntaxOn
    \NewChildSelector{eachfive}
      {
        \int_step_inline:nnnn {1}{5}{\l_tblr_childs_total_tl}
          { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tblr_childs_clist {##1} }
      }
% HTML coloring in table <--- new, added
\pretocmd{\@declaredcolor}{\my@hack@color{#1}}{}{}
\def\my@hack@color#1{\@ifundefined{\@backslashchar color@#1}{\MyDefineColor{#1}}{\relax}}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nnx }
\NewDocumentCommand \MyDefineColor { m } {
  \seq_set_split:Nnx \l_tmpa_seq {|} {#1}
  \exp_args:Nnxx \definecolor{#1} { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {1} } { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {2} }
}
    \ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother   % new, added
    \NewTableCommand\SCC[1]{\SetCell{bg=#1}}    % for coloring of a (lonely) cell
    
    \sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}, 
             table-auto-round,   % changed from
group-digits=false
}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtblr}[
  theme = fancy,
caption = {Beregning af afsætning - undergruppe 3a},
  label = {tab:afs_beregn_3a}
                ]{colspec = {@{} Q[r, si={table-format=2.0}]
                            *{2}{X[c, si={table-format=6.3}]  % <--- 
                                 X[c, si={table-format=7.3}]} % <---
                            *{3}{Q[c, si={table-format=-1.3}]}
                            *{2}{Q[c, si={table-format= 1.3}]}
                             @{}},
                 cell{1}{even[2-6]} = {c=2}{},
                 cell{2}{8-10} = {fg={HTML|202122}}, 
  % chaanged from {fg=blue!60!black},
                 row{1,2} = {guard},
                 row{3-Y} = {rowsep=0pt},
                 row{3} = {abovesep=2pt},   row{Z} = {belowsep=2pt},
                 row{eachfive} = {belowsep=1ex},
                 rowhead  = 2
                }
%% headers
    \toprule
Pkt.    & Design            &
        & Kontrol           &
        & Differens         &
        & Gns.snit $\mu$    &
  {Sigma $\sigma$} &
  {d\_max} \\
  \cmidrule[lr]{2-3} \cmidrule[lr]{4-5} \cmidrule[lr]{6-7}
    & Easting               & Northing
    & Easting               & Northing
    & Easting               & Northing 
                                & [m]
                                    & [m]
                                        & [m] \\
  \midrule
%% body of longtblr
1  & 729598,741 & 6171261,02  & 729598,743 & 6171261,029 & -0,002 & -0,009 
                                                            & -0,001 & 0,008 & 0,025 \\
2  & 729598,897 & 6171260,664 & 729598,909 & 6171260,669 & -0,012 & -0,005 \\
3  & 729598,973 & 6171260,489 & 729598,987 & 6171260,491 & -0,014 & -0,002 \\
4  & 729591,938 & 6171258,298 & 729591,935 & 6171258,284 & 0,003  & 0,014  \\
5  & 729592,087 & 6171257,93  & 729592,087 & 6171257,926 & 0,000  & 0,004  \\ 
6  & 729592,181 & 6171257,727 & 729592,184 & 6171257,726 & -0,003 & 0,001  \\
7  & 729586,791 & 6171256,205 & 729586,792 & 6171256,222 & -0,001 & -0,017 \\
8  & 729586,931 & 6171255,84  & 729586,935 & 6171255,830 & -0,004 & 0,01   \\
9  & 729587,022 & 6171255,644 & 729587,020 & 6171255,648 & 0,002  & -0,004 \\
10 & 729583,342 & 6171254,816 & 729583,347 & 6171254,816 & -0,005 & 0,000  \\ 
11 & 729583,489 & 6171254,435 & 729583,499 & 6171254,431 & -0,010 & 0,004  \\
12 & 729583,576 & 6171254,245 & 729583,561 & 6171254,249 & 0,015  & -0,004 \\
13 & 729579,337 & 6171253,176 & 729579,336 & 6171253,173 & 0,001  & 0,003  \\
14 & 729579,438 & 6171252,864 & 729579,449 & 6171252,857 & -0,011 & 0,007  \\
15 & 729579,562 & 6171252,6   & 729579,553 & 6171252,603 & 0,009  & -0,003 \\ 
16 & 729575,731 & 6171251,687 & 729575,729 & 6171251,683 & 0,002  & 0,004  \\
17 & 729575,814 & 6171251,419 & 729575,834 & 6171251,411 & -0,020 & 0,008  \\
18 & 729575,958 & 6171251,135 & 729575,952 & 6171251,134 & 0,006  & 0,001  \\
19 & 729568,597 & 6171248,783 & 729568,580 & 6171248,789 & 0,017  & -0,006 \\
20 & 729568,73  & 6171248,412 & 729568,726 & 6171248,417 & 0,004  & -0,005 \\ 
21 & 729568,795 & 6171248,231 & 729568,803 & 6171248,223 & -0,008 & 0,008  \\
22 & 729562,201 & 6171246,188 & 729562,204 & 6171246,191 & -0,003 & -0,003 \\
23 & 729562,341 & 6171245,81  & 729562,334 & 6171245,818 & 0,007  & -0,008 \\
24 & 729562,41  & 6171245,628 & 729562,408 & 6171245,631 & 0,002  & -0,003 \\
25 & 729555,891 & 6171243,616 & 729555,895 & 6171243,617 & -0,004 & -0,001 \\ 
26 & 729556,006 & 6171243,377 & 729556,003 & 6171243,377 & 0,003  & 0,000  \\
27 & 729556,112 & 6171243,069 & 729556,105 & 6171243,079 & 0,007  & -0,010 \\
28 & 729550,186 & 6171241,296 & 729550,182 & 6171241,300 & 0,004  & -0,004 \\
29 & 729550,305 & 6171241,07  & 729550,310 & 6171241,064 & -0,005 & 0,006  \\
30 & 729550,411 & 6171240,743 & 729550,415 & 6171240,747 & -0,004 & -0,004 \\ 
31 & 729538,652 & 6171236,606 & 729538,662 & 6171236,611 & -0,010 & -0,005 \\
32 & 729538,803 & 6171236,231 & 729538,816 & 6171236,234 & -0,013 & -0,003 \\
33 & 729538,879 & 6171236,044 & 729538,889 & 6171236,045 & -0,010 & -0,001 \\
34 & 729533,279 & 6171234,425 & 729533,290 & 6171234,444 & -0,011 & -0,019 \\
35 & 729533,426 & 6171234,044 & 729533,440 & 6171234,043 & -0,014 & 0,001  \\ 
36 & 729533,505 & 6171233,85  & 729533,499 & 6171233,856 & 0,006  & -0,006 \\
37 & 729528,457 & 6171232,45  & 729528,465 & 6171232,451 & -0,008 & -0,001 \\
38 & 729528,608 & 6171232,081 & 729528,612 & 6171232,077 & -0,004 & 0,004  \\
39 & 729528,686 & 6171231,903 & 729528,680 & 6171231,902 & 0,006  & 0,001  \\
40 & 729521,837 & 6171229,747 & 729521,841 & 6171229,753 & -0,004 & -0,006 \\ 
41 & 729521,985 & 6171229,364 & 729521,982 & 6171229,360 & 0,003  & 0,004  \\
42 & 729522,063 & 6171229,185 & 729522,063 & 6171229,184 & 0,000  & 0,001  \\
43 & 729517,553 & 6171227,989 & 729517,560 & 6171227,989 & -0,007 & 0,000  \\
44 & 729517,709 & 6171227,629 & 729517,708 & 6171227,634 & 0,001  & -0,005 \\
45 & 729517,78  & 6171227,442 & 729517,774 & 6171227,442 & 0,006  & 0,000  \\ 
46 & 729513,038 & 6171226,164 & 729513,042 & 6171226,161 & -0,004 & 0,003  \\
47 & 729513,198 & 6171225,787 & 729513,201 & 6171225,791 & -0,003 & -0,004 \\
48 & 729513,265 & 6171225,606 & 729513,284 & 6171225,557 & -0,019 & \SCC{HTML|FF0000} 0,049 \\
49 & 729507,361 & 6171223,854 & 729507,357 & 6171223,858 & 0,004  & -0,004 \\
50 & 729507,515 & 6171223,487 & 729507,510 & 6171223,491 & 0,005  & -0,004 \\ 
51 & 729507,589 & 6171223,298 & 729507,591 & 6171223,302 & -0,002 & -0,004 \\
52 & 729502,897 & 6171222,041 & 729502,891 & 6171222,026 & 0,006  & 0,015  \\
53 & 729503,061 & 6171221,668 & 729503,062 & 6171221,659 & -0,001 & 0,009  \\
54 & 729503,12  & 6171221,49  & 729503,117 & 6171221,496 & 0,003  & -0,006 \\
55 & 729498,329 & 6171220,185 & 729498,328 & 6171220,177 & 0,001  & 0,008  \\ 
56 & 729498,478 & 6171219,801 & 729498,488 & 6171219,807 & -0,010 & -0,006 \\
57 & 729498,557 & 6171219,624 & 729498,552 & 6171219,632 & 0,005  & -0,008 \\
58 & 729584,389 & 6171255,864 & 729584,388 & 6171255,868 & 0,001  & -0,004 \\
59 & 729517,339 & 6171228,518 & 729517,338 & 6171228,516 & 0,001  & 0,002  \\
60 & 729543,328 & 6171239,092 & 729543,333 & 6171239,102 & -0,005 & -0,010 \\ 
61 & 729558,679 & 6171245,372 & 729558,693 & 6171245,371 & -0,014 &  0,001 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: A detail, `si={table-format= 6.3}` causes `Overfull hbox`

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to `\NewChildSelector`, I tested with 6 title lines with { \int_step_inline:nnnn {6}{5}{\l_tblr_childs_total_tl}` , if I understood correctly shouldn't it be {`\int_step_inline:nnnn {2}{5}` and `row{3-Y} = {rowsep=0pt}`

Comment: @pascal974, I discover what was wrong in original answer. The third and fifth columns has 7 intrige digits, not 6 as I was blindly copy from Mico answer. Now these specification are corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the width of your table; Im a GOM so I would have thought that that might have occured to you. From the code you show you can eliminate the initial "72" from the first and third columns --- an exercise for you the reader.